# MapServer - what are some options for a GUI for map file creation?

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

What are some possible options for a GUI to manage style and map file for MapServer.

I am interested in all solutions, QGIS plugin, ArcGIS mxd or MapInfo workspace converter or else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was looking for exactly the same thing some time ago. I did find some tools, but most of them are out of active development and only support old version of mapfile syntax. But anyway here is what I've found.

[Sribe UI](http://mapgears.github.io/scribeui-site/): this is a very new project and looks promising (only support mapserver 6.0+). It is under active development but still in early phase, they've just released 0.1 version.

[MapFile viewers](https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/wiki/MapFile-viewers): There's a QGIS pulgin available

[mscompanion](https://code.google.com/p/mscompanion/): A GUI WYSIWYG Mapfile editor for MapServer running on Windows. (Very old, untouched for several years, and the latest version is compatible with mapserver 5.4.0)